# How to run VBA automatically in Excel file on SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

apologies, I'm a newbie and somewhat an Excel novice.

I have a .xlsm file that works on my computer with some code adapted from another site that enables multiple selection from drop down lists.

I wish to share this on the team SharePoint for others to contribute.

I understand that VBA will only run if individuals choose to open in the 'Desktop App'. However, when the document is uploaded it still doesn't run despite selecting Open in Desktop.

It was suggested that for it to run on SharePoint the VBA code would need to be located within a Visuall Basic "module" rather than behind a "Work sheet". However, if I cut and paste the code into a module it doesn't run at all...(not even for the file saved on my PC).

Code is as follows - apologies in advance for my limited skills in this area. Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Define variables
    
    Dim ExistingValue As String
    
    Dim NewValue As String
    
    Dim Separator As String
    
    'If an error occurs, enable events and quit the code
    
    On Error GoTo Quit
    
    'Check if the dropdown cell is changed
    
    If Target.Column = 20 Or Target.Column = 21 Or Target.Column = 49 Then
        
        'If user deletes the dropdown cell's data do nothing
        
        If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Quit
        
        'The fun begins
        
        Application.EnableEvents = FALSE
        
        NewValue = Target.Value
        
        Application.Undo
        
        ExistingValue = Target.Value
        
        If ExistingValue = "" Then
            
            Target.Value = NewValue
            
        Else
            
            'Check if the dropdown item is already selected
            
            If InStr(1, ExistingValue, NewValue) = 0 Then
                
                Target.Value = ExistingValue & ", " & NewValue
                
            Else
                
                Target.Value = ExistingValue
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
    Quit:
    
    Application.EnableEvents = TRUE
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Darren. I have the code formatted correctly within the workbook on my PC, and everything works ok. However, when it is uploaded to Sharepoint - even if the file is opened in "desktop app" the code does not run...